# Juju local behind proxy

Tags: proxy, juju

I am trying to use juju in local environment, on a VM running Ubuntu 13.04. The proxy settings for the machine to connect to the internet are set accordingly and are working. But when i try to bootstrap the juju environment i get the following error.

```
ERROR Get http://10.0.3.1:8040/provider-state: http: error connecting to proxy http://my-proxy-address:port_no: dial tcp my-proxy-address:port_no: connection timed out
```

I'm not able to resolve this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The [failing bootstrap](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/troubleshooting-local.html#bootstrap-fails) is addressed in the [Troubleshooting guide](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/troubleshooting-local.html) in the Juju documentation.

According to the documentation there may be some `.jenv` files in `~/.juju/environments/` directory. Destroy the environment, remove the files, and try bootstrapping again.  You can use the `--debug` flag to give more information about the bootstrap process.

The networking file for LXC can be found at /etc/default/lxc-net  You may need to edit this file to work with your proxy network configuration.

Failing that we have completed a [Juju Troubleshooting video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuqFaTASBTE) that might help you troubleshoot problems with Juju.  Have a look!

Comment: Hi Matt, I checked to documentation earlier, but it doesn't help. I guess the problem is with the configuration of the LXC. Can you please state what tweakings have to be done with the LXC configuration file.

Comment: gfc If you tried the steps on the Troubleshooting document and you still need help, we need more information.  Please get a copy of the error, `ls ~/.juju/environments/` and `sudo lxc-ls --fancy` and put the output in pastebin somewhere.  You can find me on IRC in #juju on Freenode.net, or I can check back here.